# Can I use PCINT0 and PCINT1 for all pin interrupts on atmega328pb?

Tags: c, avr

I am trying to make it so that  then PINB7 is pressed (which is pin of botton) LED to light up. 
PINB7 is PCINT8 on board.
So i set

```
PCICR|=(1<<1);//enable interrupts for pins 14-8
sei();
PCMSK1|=(<<PCINT8); // mask for pin 8
```

i don't get what vector i should use in ISR. From what i saw I should just do PCINT8_vect, however vector doesn't get highlighted like then i use "TIMER2_COMPB_vect".So does PCINT8 vector not exist or is there way to use PCINT0 and 1 for this?

Comment: You shouldn't take highlighting too seriously, and it's especially hard to answer any questions about highlighting if you don't even tell us what IDE you are using.  Did you try compiling code?  Was there an error?  Can you post a [mcve]?  Did you check the ATmega328PB datasheet to see what interrupt vectors exist?

Comment: @DavidGrayson  yeh my first time on overflow i should have been more  detailed .I found the answer tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently , on mega328pb , there is no vectors for individual pin interrupts but there are vectors for PCIE0,1,2,3.
0- bits 0:7
1-8:14
2-16:23
3-24:27

so if u want to use interrupt for  pin b7.
PB7 is PCINT7(can be seen in chapter about i/o ports).
So id have to enable PCIE0 in PCIRC register, correct mask it TMSK0. and use ISR(PCINT0_vect).
But if you have interrupt on   PCINT6 and PCINT7 , you need if  else in ISR to determine  which of 2 pins triggered interrupt

Comment: There are two vectors for individual pins  `INT0` for `PD2` and `INT1` for `PD3`. It can be configured to detect falling edge, rising edge or low level.  Pin change interrupts detects only the change and they have one ISR per port. And on bigger MCUs like Atmega256 pin change interrupts are not available on all ports (just four of them if I recall it correctly)